# How to apply a transition effect to 2 variables in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to make it so that the 2 colors in the background transitions smoothly to another color if you hover over it. I'm not quite sure what else to attempt here, as it is not working.
The 2 variables I am trying to transition here is `--color-start` & `--color-end`
I also wonder if it is even possible to do this without JavaScript.

```css
body {
  --color-start: rgb(238, 130, 238);
  --color-end: rgb(0, 209, 255);
  background-size: 40px 40px, 200vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #000000 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 1px), linear-gradient(to bottom left, var(--color-start) 30%, var(--color-end) 100%);
  font-family: Montserrat;
  transition: var(--color-start) 0.5s, var(--color-end) 0.5s;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
}

.middle-text {
  color: white;
}

.middle-text:hover+body {
  --color-start: rgb(0, 209, 255);
  --color-end: rgb(238, 130, 238);
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="middle-text" style="font-size:500%">Welcome to Ameglass</h1>
  <p style="color:rgb(44, 44, 44)">Press Any Key to Continue</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like the property you want to transition is `background-image`, not the variables that are used in its definition. But your selector won't work, since `.middle-text` is not a sibling of `body`.

Comment: Also, you are trying to change a parent selector on hover, which will work with [`:has()`](https://caniuse.com/css-has) - but not natively in FireFox yet (FF120 is supposed to have native `:has()` support.